# Firebase cloud functions admin create user how to call the function in react/

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've created a working cloud function in the index. I followed the documentation of firebase:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user and my function looks like that.

```html
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth?.token.coach) return "You are not a teacher!";

  return admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      email: data.email,
      emailVerified: true,
      displayName: data.firstname,
      password: data.password,
    })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      console.log("Successfully crated new user:", userRecord.uid);
      return userRecord.uid;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
      return "An error has occured";
    });
});
```

When I fire the function form my webapp I can see in the logs of that the function is called. Only the new user is not added to the authentication. So I don't think the function actually creates a new users.

Why doesn't it work? Have I placed the addUser in the wrong place?

```html
  const functions = getFunctions();
  const addUser = httpsCallable(functions, "createUser");

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ref = collection(db, "studentsByTeacher", user.uid, "Students");

    await addDoc(ref, {
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      email: email,
      password: password,
      teacherId: user.uid,
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
    });
    addUser({
      email: email,
      firstname: firstname,
      password: password,
    }).then(function (resp: any) {
      console.log(resp.data.result);
    });
    setFirstname("");
    setLastname("");
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };
```

```html
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Grid container marginTop={4}>
                <Grid item md={2} marginLeft={4}>
                  <TextField
                    label="First Name"
                    fullWidth
                    type="text"
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={firstname}
                    onChange={(event) => setFirstname(event.target.value)}
                  ></TextField>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={2} marginLeft={1}>
                  <TextField
                    label="Last Name"
                    fullWidth
                    type="text"
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={lastname}
                    onChange={(event) => setLastname(event.target.value)}
                  ></TextField>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={5} marginLeft={1}>
                  <TextField
                    label="Email"
                    fullWidth
                    type="text"
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
                  ></TextField>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid container marginTop={2}>
                <Grid item md={4} marginLeft={4}>
                  <TextField
                    label="Password"
                    fullWidth
                    type="password"
                    variant="outlined"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
                  ></TextField>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid container marginTop={4}>
                <Grid item md={4} marginLeft={4}>
                  <Button variant="contained" size="large" type="submit">
                    <Typography style={{ fontWeight: "semibold" }}>
                      ADD STUDENT
                    </Typography>
                  </Button>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the **entire** code of your Cloud Function? Do you see any trace of its execution in the Cloud Function log? Also, can you add a `catch` block in your react code? Also how do you call `handleSubmit`? Via a button? Can you show this code as well.

Comment: Thanks. Can you try calling the Cloud Function with another way than via the form submit event. E.g. via a simple button outside the form. It happens sometimes that the form is submitted before the asynchronous call is called.

Comment: I’m not versed in react but for example via a simple button.

Comment: In addition you should also await the call to `addUser()` because it is also asynchronous.

Comment: Unfortunately that also didn't work.

Comment: Can you try calling the Cloud Function with constant values, e.g. `addUser({
      email: "email@test.com",
      firstname: "firstname",
      password: "password0987",
    })`. Also are you sure that `context.auth?.token.coach` is `true`? You should add a catch block `await addUser({...}).then(function (resp: any) {...}).catch();` or better, add a global try/catch block and remove the `then()`.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I've removed the check on the context.auth?.token.coach and now the function works. So I think the problem lies with the permissions check.

Comment: Glad I could help you! I've written an anwser in line with this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion via the comments, it appears that the problem comes from the fact that the first check you do in the Callable Cloud Function (i.e. `context.auth?.token.coach`) returns `true`. Since, in this case, you return a String, the Cloud Function  Platform considers that the function has completed its work successfully and the rest of the code is not executed (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details).

Instead of sending back a String in case of error, it's better to manage errors as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors), i.e. by "throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`".

Then, I would recommend to refactor your front-end code as follows, in order to propoerly catch the error (and of course solve the problem with `context.auth?.token.coach`, maybe by using a [Custom Claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)?)

```
const functions = getFunctions();
const addUser = httpsCallable(functions, "createUser");

const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
        const ref = collection(db, "studentsByTeacher", user.uid, "Students");

        await addDoc(ref, {
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            teacherId: user.uid,
            createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
        });

        const resp = await addUser({
            email: email,
            firstname: firstname,
            password: password,
        })

        console.log(resp.data.result);

        setFirstname("");
        setLastname("");
        setEmail("");
        setPassword("");
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        // ... anything else
    }

};
```